# How can I manage sessions on two separate front-end apps from one Laravel backend?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have a Laravel API that currently manages the session authentication for a SPA  using a single table. I'd like to support a second SPA using the same API, storing the users for the second SPA in a different table.

However, I can't figure out how the best way to prevent a user who's logged into SPA1 from passing the auth guards for SPA2, since the session is stored/checked in the same place.

I'm thinking about storing a key in the session and then checking for the existence of that key in the middleware for each app. I'd love to hear other options.